# Keyboard shortcut to change font color in Libreoffice to a specific color

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I have to do a fair amount of writing in red and black in the same document.  In MS Office I would set a keyboard shortcut to switch between colors so I don't have to take my hands off the keyboard.  Something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for red and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for black.

How can I set up something similar in LibreOffice Writer?  I've poked around in *Tools* → *Customize* → *Keyboard*, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: One way I tried just now is to create two custom styles (call them Red and Blue) with appropriate font colours, and then assign shortcuts to them. But it seems the styles work on the entire line, so if you switch in the middle, the entire line's colour changes. Is that acceptable? If not, you might want to try creating macros.

Comment: @muru Unfortunately I need to have both colors in the same line, although not the same word.  I'm not sure how to work with macros in LO, but I'll poke around.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Muru's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946016/keyboard-shortcut-to-change-font-color-in-libreoffice-to-a-specific-color/1465213#comment1503783_946016) is close, but use *Character* styles, not *Paragraph* styles.

1. Press <kbd>F11</kbd> and click the icon for *Character styles*.
2. <kbd>Right-click</kbd> *Default Style*, select *New...*, and  change the font color to red.  In the *Organizer*, name the font color `Red`, then press *OK*.
3. Go to *Tools* → *Customize*, select the *Keyboard* tab, find <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and select it.
4. Under *Categories*, choose *Styles*/*Character*.  Under *Function*, select *Red*.  Then click the *Modify* button.

   [image: customize keyboard]
5. The *Character Style* for the *Default Style* is already black, so assign it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and press *OK*.
6. Finally, select words and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

   [image: change word color]

Comment: +1 for a very nicely formatted answer. When I delve into LO keyboard shortcuts this will also be valuable.

Comment: my version does not have this menu when I push F11

Comment: In my current version, the menu option is *View -> Styles*, or find the *Styles and Formatting* icon in the sidebar on the right-hand side.

Comment: @JimK can you please update your guide for the latest LO version? after I create the style like you suggest, I cannot find it in the function section when I want to define the shortcut. Cheers

Comment: @lucian: It still works in 6.4.3.2. Try following the directions again and see if you made a mistake. If that doesn't help, ask a new question with a link to this one.

Comment: thank you! you are correct, I did make a mistake! it works with the latest version too!

Comment: Thanks, answer still works.

Comment: very nice. but pressing again `Alt+R`, doesnt undo the coloring ..., not even "Clear Formatting" (Ctrl + M); what can i do?

Comment: @alexzander: Press `Ctrl+Z` to undo any recent change, or restore Default Style by pressing `Alt+B` as explained in the answer.