# Keyboard Shortcut to change font color in Libre Office Impress

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I found [an answer for writer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946016/keyboard-shortcut-to-change-font-color-in-libreoffice-to-a-specific-color/946170) but I cannot get it to work with Impress.

Was about to give up, but figured that I should at least ask if anyone has any idea on how to create a keyboard shortcut to change the font color in Impress.

Even looked into possibly creating a macro, but even after enabling macros I can't seem to be able to record any under Impress (although the option is clearly there in Writer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles in Impress are like paragraph styles in that they only apply to entire paragraphs. Also, it is not possible to create new Drawing Styles, and Presentation Styles only apply to shapes such as text boxes created with the "insert text box" option. In short, styles are recommended in Writer, but in Impress, direct formatting is best in most cases.

So, here is a macro solution. Add the following Basic code to a module in your Standard library.

```
Sub colorBlack
    colorText(RGB(0,0,0))
End Sub

Sub colorRed
    colorText(RGB(255,0,0))
End Sub

Sub colorText(color As Long)
    oSel = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getSelection()
    oCurs = oSel.getText().createTextCursorByRange(oSel)
    oCurs.CharColor = color
End Sub
```

Then go to *Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard*. Under *Category*, expand `My Macros` and the Standard library to find the module with `colorBlack` and `colorRed`. Then choose which shortcut keys to use and press *Modify* to assign them.

Comment: Important note: The updated color will not show until the slide has redrawn. You can force a redraw by switching to another slide and back again.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that problem as well. My solution was to click outside the shape to de-select it, which forced the redraw.